# Create table, by conditionally copying rows from another table - possible in MS-Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Every week, a new Excel file is generated by a CRM system, which has the date-stamp in it's file-name, but placed in a folder at a fixed location (a sharepoint URL).

This file is quite large, and usually contains anywhere between 25-30 thousand rows. Out of this, I need to create a new table, relevant to my purpose.

Rows relevant to my purpose, must match one (or more) keywords/key-phrases, from a list of 30-40 such keywords/key-phrases. This list of keywords/key-phrases, however also grows, but slowly, s.a. adding new keywords once every few months.

Is there some way to automate this manual, tedious and somewhat error-prone task ?

Comment: @pnuts, thanks for replying. Recording macro is certainly one possibility, I agree, but not having used it previously, I wasn't sure if records actions as diverse as Search, Copy-Paste, reorder (Sort) etc. I will explore that route.

Comment: @pnuts, that seems like a possibly good answer. I'd definitely upvote (minimally) or even accept. Plan to keep the question open a little longer, to see if there are any other miraculously simple and reliable alternatives, although I suspect that there may not be one.

Comment: @pnuts, the keywords are all distortions of various product names, or even some generic names, including mixed cases and some bad punctuations. I have a worksheet, whose col. A contains this list of keywords. This worksheet, I can then add to any of the "generated" Excel workbooks. Of course, today, this list is only for my reference while searching for matching rows manually. I match the keyword with cell contents of a particular col.

Comment: Need to search for the keywords, in a set of columns. E.g. I've a list of customer-names (including variations like -- full names, mnemonics, NSE stock ticker etc.), and I need to search for occurrence of those customer-names in 3 columns, say named -- "Account", "Reseller", "L2 Channel".

Comment: @pnuts, logically, looks perfect, although I'd have liked to avoid the step of putting formula on row1 and copying down, since it is not easy when there are couple of tens of thousands of rows ! Unless there is a shortcut that I am missing.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. Got a chance to try this method today, but looks like the double-click the bottom RH corner of cell, works only if the table has no merged-cells, as the merged-cells seem to fool this selection mechanism !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because three different columns (assumed below to be `B`, `D` and `F`) need to be checked, an `OR` function looks appropriate:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,keyarray,0)),
    ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,keyarray,0)),
    ISNUMBER(MATCH(F1,keyarray,0)))
```

so that a match for any of the three columns will return `TRUE`. Place this in a ‘helper’ column in the first row occupied by data (say Row 1, or adjust `B1`,`D1` and `F1` above accordingly).

`MATCH` checks to see whether, for example, the value of `B1` exists in `keyarray`, where that is the given name for the range that contains the list of keywords/key-phrases (~30-40 in number) – need not be in same sheet or workbook but if not the full path must be specified and recommended that the 'other' workbook is open when applying the formula to a new batch of data.

`0` forces an exact match only (alternatively `-1` for smallest value that is greater than or equal to `B1`, or `1` for largest.)

`MATCH` returns the location of the found value in the array (otherwise, with parameter `0`, `#N/A`). That is numeric so `ISNUMBER` tests for a number (any number) – to exclude `#N/A` results.

Hence provided any of `B1`, `D1` or `F1` is in `keyarray` the result will be `TRUE` – otherwise `FALSE`.

To copy the formula down over 25-30 thousand rows conveniently where some contain merged cells, place something (say ‘end’) in the intersection of the last occupied row and the ‘helper’ column (to prevent expanding the size of the spreadsheet unnecessarily). Copy the cell containing the formula, select the cell immediately below it then `Ctrl+Shift+Down`/Paste to fill the helper column downwards for all occupied rows, without continuing past last occupied row and with overwriting ‘end’.

Filter on ‘helper’ column for `TRUE`, select all occupied columns, copy and paste into new sheet/workbook. Delete blank rows in new sheet/workbook and save. (May choose to delete ‘helper’ column from source also.)

Ensure that when occasionally adding items to `keyarray` the named range covers the additions.

Comment: This turns out to be much simpler, and a nice compromised between what is done today, and complete automation (requiring VBA scripting, which I am not comfortable with).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bigger task wich may be solved in a vast variety of ways. But in short, YES, you can automate this.

Just to start you off:

Are you absolutely sure, that your CRM System cannot provide this information you want to extract directly?

Usually they are based on a Databasesystem, like SQL, and because you are already extracting data out of it, you might be able to modify this output to match your needs.

---

Now to the possiblities with excel:

1. Importing the base data from your CRM

you might be able to establish a data-connection to your CRM

you can create VBA-Code to import the newest file in your folder or to update an established data-connection to this new file

you can open the newest file via VBA and copy desired data into your targeted worksheet

...

2. If still needed, filtering of the data

I would suggest that you look into filters and advanced filters, vlookup, countifs and vba-code examples. There are quite some question here and in stackoverflow handling multicondition-filtering, but you would have to provide more specifics to solve this properly.

---

as a suggestion: I would split this task into getting the base-data and only if still necessary filtering it. As I see it, it should be possible to get your filtered data much erlier in the process. Or tell me otherwise :)

Comment: Thanks @Jook. This is in the context of a large corporation, with too many layers of need-to-know protection built around the core CRM system. For us, the Excel sheet is the best we can hope to gain access to! So, the problem is not technical, but policy. So, it looks like, it's either going to be Macro-recording of manual-actions, or some VBA Macro's that programmaticly pull this off.

Comment: As I suspected - I am familiar with this situation. However, it usually is in your corporations interest to provide this data as easy as possible for you - in the end, they usually buy such a CRM-system for this cause. Someone should take this to IT, but as long as there is not other way, use your own solution. In that case, you might want to start with the filtering, and then worry about automatic data import, because this should be easier.